# Star expressions in python3 comes into syntax error

Tags: python

I'm just starting to read python cookbook and I just type codes from book as follow:

```py
from numpy import mean
def drop_first_last(grades):
    first, *middle,last = grades
    return mean(middle)

test = [10, 20, 10, 5]

print (drop_first_last(test))
```

However, it comes to

```
  File "practice.py", line 3
    first, *middle, last = grades
           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Any suggestion will be appreciated.

I think that results from IDE now. I used python2 before but installed python 3 just now.
The py file is running in the Notepad++ by F5

```
cmd /k cd /d "$(CURRENT_DIRECTORY)" & python "$(FILE_NAME)" & ECHO. & PAUSE & EXIT
```

Typing python --version in cmd shows python 3.7.4
Did I get wrong with setting in Notepad++？

Comment: What do you want your code to do?

Comment: We need to see more code in order to help you.

Comment: @IMCoins that's all , I just simply try the star expressions.

Comment: and it's running in the notepad++ by cmd /k cd /d "$(CURRENT_DIRECTORY)" & python "$(FILE_NAME)" & ECHO. & PAUSE & EXIT

Comment: If you type `python --version` what does appear ?

Comment: @IMCoins python 3.7.4

Comment: This is not possible. The problem is elsewhere. As @DeepSpace said, you might be running another version of python.

Comment: @IMCoinsIm I do think so. what I try to figure out now is whether the command I used in Notepad++ is wrong?

Comment: @GanbatteKnight just add `import sys;print(sys.version)` to the code and you will see the version of the interpreter used

Comment: @DeepSpace 3.7.4 , geez, it's quite weird...

Comment: @DeepSpace It works after restarting PC.The problem possibly results from install Python 3 without restarting PC to enable ide update env. Thanks for your patience and answer.  Would you pleased to add the method about "restarting PC" to your answer so that I will accept your answer in order to save other Notepad++ newbee from suffering.

Answer (score 2):

You must be executing this code with Python 2.

A Python 2 equivalent will be:

```
def drop_first_last(grades):
    return avg(grades[1:-1])  # slicing to ignore the first and last elements in the list
```

Comment: it's running in the notepad++ by cmd /k cd /d "$(CURRENT_DIRECTORY)" & python "$(FILE_NAME)" & ECHO. & PAUSE & EXIT. And it exactly shows python 3.7.4 after typing  python --version in cmd . It really confuses me. Anything wrong